# how to select and edit text in multiple different lines

Tags: multiple-cursors

everyone I'm trying to achieve a behaviour described here [Fundamentals of multiple-cursors](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/751/fundamentals-of-multiple-cursors).

Particulraly the following comment:

`Edit several places simultaneously. Either mark several instances of a string like before, but cancel the selection (but not the cursors) immediately using C-g`

The only problem is that there is not detailed explanation or description of the commands to achieve that.

Can someone please give an example on can I accomplish that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For example, if I have the following text:

```
var1 = 17

var1 = var1 + 34

function(var1)
```

Say I want to change the name of my variable from `var1` to `myvar1`. To use the recipe from the linked answer, the steps are:

1. Select the first instance of `var1`
2. Mark the next instance of `var1` with `mc/mark-next-like-this`, which I have bound to `C->`. Repeat until all the `var1` are marked
3. Alternatively, you could use `mc/mark-all-like-this`, which I have bound to `C-c C-<`, to mark all instances of `var1` at once.
4. Press `C-g`. This cancels the selection of `var1`, but leaves a cursor at the beginning of each one.
5. type `my`, which will then be inserted in front of each instance of `var1`.
6. type `<enter>` when you're done

Obviously you can mix and match this in all kinds of ways, once you get the hang of it.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. Just a clarification what if your code is like this:


`var1 = 17`
`new_var = myvar + 34`
`function(input)`

Let's say I want to edit and `var1`, `myvar` and `input`
how can I achieve that?

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't know of a way to mark multiple things that aren't either the same text (eg, "var1"), or at the same column in consecutive lines. ie, you can put a cursor at the beginnings of a bunch of lines, the end of a bunch of lines, or at column 5 of a bunch of lines. It's may be possible, but the normal workflow is designed around modifying multiple instances of the *same* name, or adding text to the beginning or end of a bunch of lines.

Comment: @Tyler There is the command `mc/add-cursor-on-click` which you can bind to a mouse button (with modifiers, say). There is also the `ace-mc` package that uses `ace-jump` style selection of multiple cursor locations.