# How can I apply a keyboard macro to every line that starts with rectangle mark region

Tags: region, keyboard-macros, rectangle

Lets suppose I would like to edit my text and to add comments to the column in the text. This is my text:

```
something-text1  foobar1 something-text1
something-text2  foobar2 something-text2
---
something-textn  foobarn something-textn
```

I want to add comments just after the words `foobar`. I do the following: (`||` is cursor):

```
||foobar1
```

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `kmacro-start-macro-or-insert-counter` <kbd>M-x</kbd> `forward-word`

```
;; comment
```

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `backward-word` <kbd>M-x</kbd> `next-line` <kbd>M-x</kbd> `kmacro-end-or-call-macro`

Now I can repeat this keyboard macro on every line with the word `foobar` with
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `kmacro-start-macro-or-insert-counter` or 
<kbd>C-u</kbd>  `kmacro-start-macro-or-insert-counter` and apply the command  times.

I would like to do the same with `rectangle-mark`. I would like to make
region with <kbd>C-x SPC</kbd> <kbd>C-u</kbd>  <kbd>С-n</kbd>:

```
something-text1  ||foobar1 something-text1
something-text2  ||foobar2 something-text2
---
something-textn  ||foobarn something-textn
```

Then I eval <kbd>M-x</kbd> `kmacro-end-or-call-macro`, but it doesn't work in the way it works with help of above-mentioned command.

How can I apply a keyboard macro to every line that starts with rectangle mark region?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can do this with rectangular regions, but it's a perfect situation for multiple cursors:

[Fundamentals of multiple-cursors](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/751/fundamentals-of-multiple-cursors)

https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el

In your case, starting with point before `foobar1`, call `M-x set rectangular-region-anchor`, navigate to the next line until you have a point before every `foobar`. Then `forward-word` moves all of your cursors to the end of `foobarN`, and you can enter the text you want.

Lots of options and variants to consider, see the links.